# gerar json dentro de loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

preciso de uma ajuda:

Tenho o seguinte json

```
var jsonString = "{ \"0%\" : { \"margin-left\":\"-0%\"},";
    jsonString += " \"25%\" : { \"margin-left\":\"-0%\"},";
    jsonString += " \"30%\" : { \"margin-left\":\"-100%\"},";
    jsonString += " \"50%\" : { \"margin-left\":\"-100%\"},";
    jsonString += " \"55%\" : { \"margin-left\":\"-200%\"},";
    jsonString += " \"75%\" : { \"margin-left\":\"-200%\"},";
    jsonString += " \"80%\" : { \"margin-left\":\"-300%\"},";
    jsonString += " \"100%\" : { \"margin-left\":\"-300%\"}}";

jsonString = JSON.parse(jsonString);

$.keyframe.define([
  $.extend(
      { name: 'tocaSlide' }, 
          jsonString
      )
]);
```

Funciona para os meus propósitos.

Mas da forma que está, tenho um var `jsonString` estático.

Preciso que seja `dinâmico`.

Então, estou gerando ele dentro de um `loop for`, mas está dando erro.

Gostaria de saber onde estou errando.

```
  var jsonString ={};   

  for (i = 0; i < quantasImagens; i++) {    

  tMin = t + tempoTransicao;
  tMax = t + tamanhoIntervalos; 
  t+=tamanhoIntervalos;

  if(i==0) tMin=0;
  if(i==quantasImagens) tMax=100;         

  jsonString += "'" + tMin + "%' : { 'margin-left':'-" + tempoImagens + "%'],";
  jsonString += "'" + tMax + "%' : { 'margin-left':'-" + tempoImagens + "%'},";

  tempoImagens+=100;

  }


  jsonString = JSON.parse(jsonString );
```

Answer (score 2):

Podes pensar em "montar um objeto" em vez de pensar em strings que devem ser transformadas num objeto...

Acho que o que procuras seria algo assim:

```js
var obj = {};

for (i = 0; i < quantasImagens; i++) {

  tMin = t + tempoTransicao;
  tMax = t + tamanhoIntervalos;
  t += tamanhoIntervalos;

  if (i == 0) tMin = 0;
  if (i == quantasImagens) tMax = 100;

  obj[tMin + '%'] = { 'margin-left': '-' + tempoImagens + '%'};
  obj[tMax + '%'] = { 'margin-left': '-' + tempoImagens + '%'};
  tempoImagens += 100;
}


console.log(obj);
```

Nota: a condição `if (i == quantasImagens) tMax = 100;` nunca vai ser alcançada pois o loop vai parar quando o `i < quantasImagens`.

Comment: deu o seguinte erro: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0%' of undefined

Comment: @CarlosRocha sim, claro erro meu, tinha `var obj = obj;` e não `var obj = {};`.

Comment: Desculpa, aqui postei errado. Mas no drreamweaver stá var obj = obj. e não funcionou mesmo assim. Tem ideia de que pode ser? Veja www.hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/slide2.php

Comment: @CarlosRocha esse site dá-me `500 Internal Server Error`. Coloca um exemplo do `quantasImagens` e das variáveis que são definidas fora do código para montar um exemplo a funcionar.

Comment: Então, @Sergio. Bom Dia! Para mim abre normal aqui. Talvez você esteja colocando espaços na URL! O erro que me retorna é esse: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0%' of undefined". Isso no Chrome. Já no Fireox, o erro é "TypeError: obj is undefined"

Comment: @CarlosRocha agora já abriu. Tens `var obj = obj;` no código. Corrige para `var obj = {};`

Comment: corrigido. Funcionou. Mas, como sempre, ocorreu um erro de lógica! Pode me ajudar? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/250778/loop-for-passando-de-100